# Adding commas to variable numbers from php to a tag

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I keep seeing this question asked, but I can't find any specific answers. If anyone can help me out that would be amazing!

Im building my first wordpress website that has a listing price in each thumbnail. But the price on it doesn't have commas at all.
fieldcommercial.net/listings-2

On the wordpress dashboard there's a custom javascript editor box that allows me to add custom script. I was wondering if there was a way to just get the element by tag and just add commas to whatever number is in the tags. Ideally this would have to work for all the prices listed on the page.

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("meta-offer"); 
var numComma = targetDiv.getElementsByTagName("span");

function addCommas(n){
    var numComma=  /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function(w){
        THIS IS WHERE IM LOST ON WHAT I CAN DO PLEASE HELP
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
function addCommas(n) {
  n = parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);
  return n.replace(/./g, function(v, w, x) {
    return w && v !== "." && ((x.length - w) % 3 === 0) ? ',' + v : v;
  });

}
```

now if your pricing is in the `meta-offer` div, you can do the following

```
$(".meta-offer").each(function() {
  $(this).html(addCommas($(this).html()))
})
```

since wordpress dashboard already has jQuery you can use it without any problems